# Making a custom vertical line marker in legend with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a figure with a lot of horizontal lines, each with its own label. I also have a few vertical lines with labels as well. By default, pyplot.legend() shows these labels with horizontal line markers and I want to visually differentiate my vertical line labels from my horizontal line labels. Are there any ideas on how to do this? Below is a simple command to plot a line.

```
plt.axvline( x=10, linestyle='-',color='black',label='vertical line')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Also:

I'm aware of this suggestion at 
[Legend with vertical line in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53122592/legend-with-vertical-line-in-matplotlib) but I am not sure how to implement it for a single label in the legend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do it for multiple vertical legends. I chose very simple data to provide a working solution. You can extend the concept to your actual data

```
from matplotlib import lines

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.plot([0, 5], [1, 1], label='y=1')
plt.plot([0, 5], [2, 2], label='y=2')
plt.plot([0, 5], [3, 3], label='y=3')

handles, _  = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

vertical_pos = [5, 7, 10]
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']

for x, c in zip(vertical_pos, colors):
    plt.plot([x, x], [0, 3], color=c, label='Vertical x=%s' %x)

_, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

for c in colors:
    vertical_line = lines.Line2D([], [],  marker='|', linestyle='None', color=c,
                          markersize=10, markeredgewidth=1.5)
    handles.append(vertical_line)

plt.legend(handles, labels)
```

**EDIT** (Using `axvline` instead of `plot`)

```
for x, c in zip(vertical_pos, colors):
    ax_ = plt.axvline( x=x, linestyle='-', color=c, label='Vertical x=%s' %x)

_, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

for c in colors:
    vertical_line = lines.Line2D([], [],  marker='|', linestyle='None', color=c,
                          markersize=10, markeredgewidth=1.5)
    handles.append(vertical_line)

plt.legend(handles, labels)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this looks pretty close to what I'd like to do. Do you know of any way to implement the use of axvline rather than the plot command combined with line2D?

Comment: @DaxFeliz: Check my edited answer.  Does it serve your purpose?